# vertical align or margin 0? float in conjunction with these properties

Tags: css

I'm creating a header that holds an image (logo) and a navigation.

The UL for the navigation is floated right within the header div. This places it at the top of the div but I'd like to align it to the bottom.

What is the best way to do this?

Have tried vertical align, which seems to do nothing and have tried position property too (bottom:0) but does not work.

I'm sure this is a common problem.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS:

```
.header {position:relative}
.header ul {position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Interesting that firebug was not producing these results I had to just code it for the effect to work. For future reference could you let me know the reasoning of having to set the parent element to ahve a position relative? Don't get why?

Comment: Well it's in the CSS specifications. In order to position a children element with absolute, the parent element must have a relative position... I've never fully understood why :)